# How do I get the middle point of faces to show in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, faces

How do I get the middle point of faces to show in edit mode? I always see it in videos, but have no idea why I don't have it and how to search for this function[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dot in the middle of faces only shows when you are in face select mode - that is, the mode whereby you can select entire faces rather than just edges or individual vertices.

I seem to recall it used to be enabled by default, so perhaps it was disabled by default in an update at some point. Either way, you can re-enable this behaviour in the **Viewport Overlays** menu, accessed from the drop-down button next to the symbol with the two circles shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Note that the required option only appears in edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the *Mesh Edit Mode > Center* option in the *Viewport Overlays*:

[image]